# Is there a BackgroundWorker replacement for .NET Compact Framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I want to use something similar to the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), which is known from the full .NET Framework, on mobile devices. Sadly it is not available in the compact framework.

What can I use instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an MSDN site discussing the [Background Processing Techniques on the CF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446488.aspx).

The most common option is to use [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) instead of a BackgroundWorker, although there are other options.

Answer (score 2):

There is implementation of BackgroundWorker for CF:
http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2004/12/backgroundworker-sample.html

Comment: you still can reach this site using waybackmachine: http://web.archive.org/web/20050102232047/http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2004/12/backgroundworker-sample.html <p>It helped me alot. There is a drop in replacement class which needs only minor fixes.It's "only" vb-code but there are numerous tools online to convert to C#.

Comment: I uploaded the C# Version to pastebin for your convenience:  http://pastebin.com/WS4reY8p       Aproppos:This code uses QueueUserWorkitem Class internaly

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/pages/BackgroundWorkerEx.aspx) is an implementation that was created using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).  You could use Reflector to check out various implementations within the .NET framework

Answer (score 0):

There is a framework, called [Smart Device Framework by OpenNETCF](https://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework.aspx), which tries to fill the gap between the compact framework and the full .NET framework. This framework contains and provides a [`BackgroundWorker`](https://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/8d64e13e-fb74-a77f-9058-d7bc509745fc.htm) implementation.

This framework is available as a community version, which can be used for free.

From the old version `1.x` is also the source code directly available from [here](https://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework.aspx) (scroll down to the last link). This source code is similar to the link, which @Filip Navara provided.