# Help me solve this Threading issue with GPS

Tags: c#, multithreading, compact-framework, gps, iasyncresult

I have a GPS class which i obviously use to acquire the latitudes and longitudes.

The UpdateData() is called when the gps state or location is changed. So i make sure that both the Latitude and Longitude is valid and then i make the DataReady bool equal to true.

So i use this code in a fairly n00b fashion where i use a Timer (Windows Form's one) and check getGPSCoordinates() every 10 seconds to see whether a valid location is found (getGPSCoordinates() is not null) and if not, do the rest of code. This is used, as it may take from 10 seconds to maybe even 1 minute to get a clear gps signal.

So although this works fine, i know this is not the correct way to do this. I think whole GPS business should be carried on a separate thread and it should notify the main thread that the location is changed and the data is ready.

Can someone point me on the correct way of handling these kinds of business? Should i use `IAsyncResult` to notify the main thread?

```
bool DataReady = false;

private void UpdateData()
        {

            if (gps.Opened)
            {
                if (position != null)
                {

                    if (position.LatitudeValid)
                    {
                        Latitude =  position.Latitude.ToString();
                    }


                    if (position.LongitudeValid)
                    {
                        Longitude = position.Longitude.ToString();

                    }

                    if (Latitude != null && Longitude != null)
                        DataReady = true;          


                }



            }


 public string getGPSCoordinates()
        {
            if (DataReady)
            {
                return String.Format("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=500x500&markers=color:red|label:A|{0},{1}&zoom=15&maptype=hybrid", Latitude, Longitude);
            }
            else
                return null;
        }


        }
```

Comment: There is actually a very similar idea in this MSDN entry:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, this is supported in .NET Framework 4. I am targeting .NET Compact Framework 3.5

Comment: Of course, didn't spot that.  However to marshal something back onto a specific thread, the thead needs to be polling a queue or something (think Message Pump in WinForms).  If you are going back to the UI, this would be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a `BackgroundWorker` - however this isn't natively supported in the Compact Framework.  Again however, this can be addressed:

[Is there a BackgroundWorker replacement for .NET Compact Framework 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323596/net-compact-fw-3-5-background-worker)

You can then call into your background worker whenever your UI timer ticks (make sure to pause your UI timer until you get a response).

If you cannot use the implemented `BackgroundWorker` from that question, you will need to maintain a Queue or List that both the UI and the background can see.  Using a normal thread will likely mean registering a callback (fairly standard, using your `IAsyncResult` idea) however this callback is run on an unknown, arbitrary thread - this makes updating your UI a little finicky.

Comment: I don't need to update the UI. I just need to get the GPS result to a string so i can send an SMS :)

Comment: Then a callback will be fine, but subsequently if it's not visible to the user then stick with your timer implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are planning to use your app on the Space Shuttle, I cannot come up with a good reason to burn a resource as expensive as a thread on this task.  A Windows Forms Timer is fine.  Do reduce the Interval to, say, a second as long as you haven't received a good measurement so the user won't have to wait so long.  Once you do, increase the Interval.  Although I doubt it makes much difference.

Answer (score 1):

When you have instaled the CF SDK you probably also have a GPS demo on your HD. It uses the new GPS middleware driver, and if you don't mind using that it is a good starting point. It has an event that signals a situation change. It will fire about 1/sec when you're moving.

Comment: Yes I am using the GPS Demo from the CF SDK. But my problem is what if a GPS signal cannot be acquired immediately as the user is inside a tunnel or something? So i want it to run until it gets a signal :)

Comment: If you use the event then that is not an issue.

Comment: So you mean i don't have to query every X seconds whether a GPS signal is fixed and a location is acquired?

Comment: IIR it has LocationChanged and StatusChanged events. And they do exactly what they say.

Comment: Yes i agree. But the issue is that in the provided sample, it keeps on checking whether `position != null` and `position.LatitudeValid` etc. So which makes me think that although the LocationChanged or StatusChanged events are fired, it does not necessarily mean that the coordinates are ready.