# Animated Busy Indicator in Compact Framework 2.0

Tags: c#, progress-bar, compact-framework, animated-gif, busyindicator

So I'm pulling some stuff from a database via a different thread, and want the form to remain usable while doing so, and also want to show the user a progress indicator until the DB code finishes.

In 'normal' winforms I'd use a `ProgressBar` with the `ProgressBarStyle` set to `Continuous`, but CF doesn't have that. Neither does it seem to support animated GIFs in a `PictureBox` (which would have been an easy way).

So what are my options for doing something like this?

EDIT: Don't want to use an hourglass mouse cursor because that implies to the user that the UI is busy (it's not).

Thanks

Comment: Add a hidden progressbar to the form. Show it when the long running task is started. You need to use another thread or background worker to update the progressbar. This must be done by an Invoke, as the thread can not access the GUI directly. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309193/c-sharp-progressbar-threading-mobile-6 and possibly http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2010/06/01/mobile-development-easy-to-use-background-thread-with-gui-update/

Answer (score 0):

You could look for a 3rd party progress bar control that supports the `Continuous` progress bar style, or a control that supports animated gifs - you're not the first running into this limitation, but I'm not sure if there are any good ones out there.

Rolling your own "continuous" progress bar `UserControl` shouldn't be very hard, you get a decent result with just a timer to call `Invalidate`, and using `Graphics.FillRectangle` in the `Paint` event.

An alternative to an animated gif control could be to create a "film strip" `UserControl`, where you provide an image (non-gif) that contains all "frames" of the gif layed out horizontally or vertically. Again you'd need a timer to call `Invalidate` and increase the frame number, and `Graphics.DrawImage` has an overload to specify which portion of the film strip image is drawn.

Instead of the timer you could use @josef's comment to increment the "current frame" whenever the worker thread has finished a portion of the work. The animated gif's "movement" would then actually show the user that work is being done.